# Destructure a function parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have function called `displayUserDetail` with a an api object passed as a parameter called `userData` from this API — https://randomuser.me/api.

Here's an example API response (trimmed down):

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "peter",
        "last": "morris"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "4330 avondale ave",
        "city": "mackay",
        "state": "tasmania",
        "postcode": 4247,
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "-79.8202",
          "longitude": "-177.8268"
        },
        "timezone": {
          "offset": "+7:00",
          "description": "Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
        }
      },
      "email": "peter.morris@example.com",
      "login": {
        "uuid": "cad308a3-5d94-4269-872b-d0a473c4a269",
        "username": "blackpeacock867",
        "password": "josephin",
        "salt": "x2MrizMY",
        "md5": "8a5298049f819b7ffab05853b6480c8c",
        "sha1": "7dde7e2aa7e7b3efdbec903fccf7f61d53c6c6dd",
        "sha256": "aac87211a73f52df4b54932ee9a4deaabd51c703249f762b8e518f121eeb7b86"
      },
      "dob": {
        "date": "1947-01-10T18:33:20Z",
        "age": 72
      },
      "registered": {
        "date": "2012-12-14T12:51:06Z",
        "age": 6
      },
      "phone": "04-2726-1355",
      "cell": "0407-597-184",
      "id": {
        "name": "TFN",
        "value": "280671361"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/26.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/26.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "AU"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "26dbd13d59ab09ca",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.2"
  }
}
```

From this, I'm required to get `username` and `picture` from this api using destructuring.

```
const displayUserDetail = (userData) => {
  if (!userData) return;
  // ???
}
```

How do I, using destructing, create a statement to obtain the `username` and `picture` from the API response?

Comment: 1)Your question is unclear 2)`!user data` will throw error. 3) give example object

Comment: I have no idea. What is `userData` supposed to be here? What is "an api object"? You'll need to describe the data that you expect. (BTW, destructuring is just another way of describing what you expect an object/array to look like)

Comment: Typo, should be (!userData)

Comment: `const { displayUserDetail } = userData;` ??

Comment: @p.s.w.g the expected data is from an api call https://randomiser.me/api/

Comment: *"create a statement that restructures the userData parameter and obtain the api object property"*. Don't destructure in the parameter. Inside the function, do `const { api } = userData`. Now you have both `userData` and `api`

Comment: @YemiEsuga That link doesn't work for me, but in any case, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55135787/edit) your question to include the description of what `userData` *actually* looks like as well as exactly what properties you need to pull out of it or how you want to restructure it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 destructuring function parameter - naming root object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051011/es6-destructuring-function-parameter-naming-root-object) and [Destructuring assignment in function call while preserving the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145876)

Comment: @p.s.w.g this has been reworded. Api URL <https://randomuser.me/api>  Required to get name and picture from the api using destructing.

Comment: @YemiEsuga I've taken the liberty of adding an example result and trying to clarify your question. This is the result I get from that API, but if you're calling it with different parameters and getting a different structure as a result, please make sure the question matches the *actual* result object you need to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring like so:

```
const displayUserDetail = (userData) => {
  const {
    login: username
  } = userData
  const {
    picture
  } = userData
  console.log(username)
  console.log(picture)
}

let data = {
  "results": [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "title": "mr",
      "first": "peter",
      "last": "morris"
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "4330 avondale ave",
      "city": "mackay",
      "state": "tasmania",
      "postcode": 4247,
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": "-79.8202",
        "longitude": "-177.8268"
      },
      "timezone": {
        "offset": "+7:00",
        "description": "Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
      }
    },
    "email": "peter.morris@example.com",
    "login": {
      "uuid": "cad308a3-5d94-4269-872b-d0a473c4a269",
      "username": "blackpeacock867",
      "password": "josephin",
      "salt": "x2MrizMY",
      "md5": "8a5298049f819b7ffab05853b6480c8c",
      "sha1": "7dde7e2aa7e7b3efdbec903fccf7f61d53c6c6dd",
      "sha256": "aac87211a73f52df4b54932ee9a4deaabd51c703249f762b8e518f121eeb7b86"
    },
    "dob": {
      "date": "1947-01-10T18:33:20Z",
      "age": 72
    },
    "registered": {
      "date": "2012-12-14T12:51:06Z",
      "age": 6
    },
    "phone": "04-2726-1355",
    "cell": "0407-597-184",
    "id": {
      "name": "TFN",
      "value": "280671361"
    },
    "picture": {
      "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/26.jpg",
      "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/26.jpg",
      "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg"
    },
    "nat": "AU"
  }],
  "info": {
    "seed": "26dbd13d59ab09ca",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.2"
  }
}

data.results.forEach(userData => displayUserDetail(userData));
```

Comment: how do i create a statement that de-structures the userData that is thr parameter passed and obtain the api property from it

Comment: That's exactly what the answer is showing @YemiEsuga.

Comment: I get an error, ' you have not destructured the 'result' property of the 'userData' parameter passed to 'displayUserDetail'

Comment: @YemiEsuga seems like you've updated the data. I've updated the answer with those edits.